# Use --rcfile option when running a login bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to know if it's posible to run a login bash but using a custom initialization file instead of ~/bashrc

`bash --rcfile "myfile" -l`

Comment: The default Ubuntu `~/.profile` doesn't do much more than source the user's `~/.bashrc` anyhow - are you sure you can't achieve what you want using a *non*-login shell (which **will** accept the custom `--rcfile`)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that is not possible, see the Note in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/chsh.1.html

Comment: Do you know if there is a different way to achieve what I want? i.e. use the login bash with a different login script. I want this because sometimes I need a configuration for bash and sometimes other.

Comment: Create different accounts, and give each account a different .bashrc.
Or the approach of https://superuser.com/questions/412384/different-bashrc-files-for-different-login-nodes